# How more effectively find the minimal composition from n sets that satisfies the given condition?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

We have N sets of triples,like

```
1. { (4; 0,1), (5 ; 0.3), (7; 0,6) }
2. { (7; 0.2), (8 ; 0.4), (1 ; 0.4) }
...
N. { (6; 0.3), (1; 0.2), (9 ; 0.5) }
```

and need to choose only one pair from each triple, so that the sum of the first members in pair will be minimal, but also we have a condition that sum of the second members in pair must be not less than a given P number.

We can solve this by sorting all possible pair combinations with the sum of their first members (3 ^ N combinations), and in that sorted list choose the first one which also satisfies the second condition. 
Could you please help to suggest a better, non trivial solution for this problem?

Comment: Looks like a kind of assignment problem. Perhaps might be solved with linear programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no constraints on the values inside your triplets, then we are facing a pretty general version of [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), more specifically a 0-1 linear programming problem, as it can be represented as a system of equations with every coefficient being 0 or 1. You can find the possible approaches on the wiki page, but there is no fast-and-easy solution for this problem in general.

Alternatively, if the second numbers of each pair (the ones that need to sum up to `>= P`) are from a small enough range, we could view this as Dynamic Programming problem similar to a [Knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem. "Small enough" there is a bit hard to define because the original data has non-integer numbers. If they were integers, then the algorithmic complexity of solution I will describe is `O(P * N)`. For non-integer numbers, they need to be first converted to integers by multiplying them all, as well as `P`, by a large enough number. In your example, the precision of each number is 1 digit after zero, so multiplying by 10 is enough. Hence, the actual complexity is `O(M * P * N)`, where M is the factor everything was multiplied by to achieve integer numbers.

After this, we are essentially solving a modified Knapsack problem: instead of constraining the weight from above, we are constraining it from below, and on each step we are choosing a pair from a triplet, as opposed to deciding whether to put an item into the knapsack or not.

Let's define a function `minimum_sum[i][s]` which at values `i, s` represents the minimum possible sum (of first numbers in each pair we took) we can achieve if the sum of the second numbers in pairs taken so far is equal to `s` and we already considered the first `i` triplets. One exception to this definition is that `minimum_sum[i][P]` has the minimum for all sums exceeding `P` as well. If we can compute all values of this function, then `minimum_sum[N][P]` is the answer. The function values can be computed with something like this:

```
minimum_sum[0][0]=0, all other values are set to infinity
for i=0..N-1:
  for s=0..P:
    for j=0..2:
      minimum_sum[i+1][min(P, s+B[i][j])] = min(minimum_sum[i+1][min(P, s+B[i][j])], minimum_sum[i][s] + A[i][j]
```

`A[i][j]` here denote the first number in i-th triplet's j-th pair, and `B[i][j]`  denote the second number of the same triplet.

This solution is viable if `N` is large, but `P` is small and precision on `B`s isn't too high. For instance, if `N=50`, there is little hope to compute `3^N` possibilities, but with `M*P=1000000` this approach would work extremely fast.

Python implementation of the idea above:

```
def compute(A, B, P):
  n = len(A)
  # note that I use 1,000,000 as “infinity” here, which might need to be increased depending on input data
  best = [[1000000 for i in range(P + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)]
  best[0][0] = 0
  for i in range(n):
    for s in range(P+1):
      for j in range(3):
        best[i+1][min(P, s+B[i][j])] = min(best[i+1][min(P, s+B[i][j])], best[i][s]+A[i][j])
  return best[n][P]
```

Testing:

```
A=[[4, 5, 7], [7, 8, 1], [6, 1, 9]]
# second numbers in each pair after scaling them up to be integers
B=[[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 4], [3, 2, 5]]

In [7]: compute(A, B, 0)
Out[7]: 6

In [14]: compute(A, B, 7)
Out[14]: 6

In [15]: compute(A, B, 8)
Out[15]: 7

In [20]: compute(A, B, 13)
Out[20]: 14
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have some questions, you have write let's define a function minimum_sum[i][s],but seems it is used as a matrix, also with this code minimum_sum[i][P] doesn't give the answer for a little example, could you please help to check it again?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; minimum_sum is indeed a function in mathematical sense, but when we compute its values programmatically, it's convenient to represent it as a matrix. I edited the answer to provide a sample Python implementation, and it seems to produce correct results for the example in the description. Could you please provide an example it breaks for?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, perhaps that was my mistake.